# The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: python, installation

I've installed python, and added it's path to system variables "C:\Python27" but when typing "python" to powershell, I get error mentioned in title. I also can't run it from cmd.

And yes, my python folder is in c directory.

Comment: Did you restart powershell since you installed Python?

Comment: Yep. Even restarted pc since.

Comment: What if you try the full path to python.exe? What does it say then?

Comment: Sadly still the same. :(

Comment: Do you mean it's saying it's not recognized? I think we're missing something obvious, this will be easiest if you provide: 
1) screenshots of your C:\Python27 directory contents; 
2) your PATH contents; e.g. run in powershell: ls env: | Where-Object {$_.name -eq 'Path' } | select -ExpandProperty value ; 
3) screenshot of the full path to python.exe command typed in powershell with the result.

Comment: My python folder: http://i.imgur.com/LFTsNEm.png  - I also tried running that command in powershell, and got this: http://i.imgur.com/Z34bmQP.png and my sytem variables: http://i.imgur.com/qRsMVWB.png - I also trieda adding /python and /python.exe at end and got same error.

Comment: Ah okay. It could be the name of the system variable should be PATH not Comspec? Can you also give the error when you run: "C:\Python27\python.exe" in powershell?

Comment: When I run "C:\Python27\python.exe" I get this: http://i.imgur.com/3ocl7Qj.png - Which I think is the same message as it should appear when only typing "python", right?

Comment: I'm dumb, haha. Yeah, I added python path under comspec, instead of path. Thanks. God it working now. :))

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 1):

Type .\python.exe .\

PS C:\Python27> .\python.exe .\PRACTICE.py

Typing only python will not get recognized by windows.